# Disable rendering of examples and schema under all the operations in Swagger UI

Tags: swagger-ui, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

Under each operation there is a section that shows "Example Value" and "Schema". I want to disable rendering that section completely. How can this be done?

Comment: May I ask why? How would your users know how the request body should look like, or what kind of data the operation returns?

Comment: @Helen Because in this particular case it takes time to generate and it will only be used for testing the operations. Unfortunately this section gets rendered with it.